# What can I use as an equivalent of python zip in mathematica inside of Sum[]?

Tags: summation, python

I want to take two lists of the same length: widths and weights, and sum a function (of 3 variables) over a single index using the elements from both lists that have that index. Then I want to plot the function.

If I only sum over one of the lists, I can use

```
scatterfunc[x1_, x2_, y1_] = 
  Sum[y1/(4*x1) + (1 - y1)/(4*x2) - 
  y1/(gamma + x1) - (1 - y1)/(gamma + x2), {gamma, widths}];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[scatterfunc[x1, x2, y1], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {y1, 0, 1}]
```

But I've been unable to find the equivalent of python's zip(widths,weights) in order to sum over a single index using both lists. I want something like

```
scatterfunc[x1_, x2_, y1_] = 
  Sum[y1/(4*x1) + (1 - y1)/(4*x2) - 
  alpha*y1/(gamma + x1) - (1 - y1)/(gamma + x2), {{gamma,alpha}, zip[widths,weights]}];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[scatterfunc[x1, x2, y1], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {y1, 0, 1}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `zip()` is effectively the same as `Transpose[]`, but your problem looks as if it will be better served by `MapThread[]` + `Total[]`.

Comment: You can do something like `Sum[...ww[[1]]...ww[[2]],{ww,Transpose@{widths,weights}} ]`. Where `ww[[1]]` is width, and `ww[[2]]` is weight.

Comment: You don't even need `Sum` at all because `Plus` and `Times` automatically thread over lists. Start by reading [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CombineAndRearrangeLists.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CombineAndRearrangeLists.html)

Comment: @N.J.Evans, this worked perfectly. I had tried transpose, but without '@'. I'm not super familiar with mathematica. What does '@' do?

Comment: @chia, `f @ x` is just the same as `f[x]`; a prefix form of function application to a single argument.

Comment: What guess who says, and you can read some of the posts here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users to start understanding how mathematica works. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @N.J.Evans, this solved my problem.

```
scatterfunc[x1_, x2_, y1_] = 
  Sum[y1/(4*x1) + (1 - y1)/(4*x2) - 
  ww[[2]]*y1/(ww[[1]] + x1) - (1 - y1)/(ww[[1]] + x2), {ww, 
  Transpose@{widths, weights}}];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[scatterfunc[x1, x2, y1], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {y1, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Consider `Total[y1/(4*x1) + (1 - y1)/(4*x2) - weights y1/(widths + x1) - (1 - y1)/(widths + x2)]` to exploit listability.

Answer (score 2):

In python, the zip function does this:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

You can do this in the Wolfram Language, for example, with MapThread:

```
x = {1,2,3};
y = {4,5,6};
MapThread[ List, {x, y} ]  (* gives {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6}} *)
```

Comment: Isn't `Transpose[]` more "traditional"?

Comment: Also, if one wants the full generality of `zip()`, `Flatten[]` with a properly set second argument might be more appropriate.